# Store result of array.sort in another variable

Tags: javascript, arrays, sorting

This seems like a simple question but I can't find much info on this.

```
var array1 = new Array(4, 3, 1, 2, 0, 5);
var array2 = array1;
array2.sort(function(a, b) {
    return a - b;
})
```

**Expected behavior:** array2 is sorted and array1 is in the original order starting with 4.

**Actual result:** both arrays are sorted.

How can I sort array1 - while maintaining array1 and storing the results of the sort in array2? I thought that doing `array2 = array1` would copy the variable, not reference it. However, in Firefox's console both arrays appear sorted.

Comment: `var array2 = array1.slice();`

Comment: Why is the default behavior to reference the original array instead of copying it?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7486085/copying-array-by-value-in-javascript. Some methods are doing changes on reference, some create new array. Check array documentation.

Comment: Should have realized that the two arrays are one and the same not just with the sort function. I guess that basically makes this a duplicate question, it just wasn't obvious at first the two arrays are always the same not just with the sort function.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[You can copy a array with slice method](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7486085/copying-array-by-value-in-javascript)

```
var array1 = new Array(4, 3, 1, 2, 0, 5);
var array2 = array1.slice();
```

Comment: Note that this makes a shallow copy, which should be fine for the OP's array of numbers but may or may not be enough with an array of objects.

Answer (score 1):

That's becasue with `var array2 = array1;` you're making a new reference to the object, so any manipulation to array2 will affect array1, since the're basically the same object.

JS doesn't provide a propner `clone` function/method, so try this widely adopted workarround:

```
var array1 = new Array(4, 3, 1, 2, 0, 5);
var array2 = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(array1));
array2.sort(function(a, b) {
    return a - b;
});
```

Hope it helps :)

Comment: *"you're making a shallow copy of the object,"* - Nope, you're not making a copy of the object at all, you're just making a second reference to the same object.

Comment: @nnnnnn that's more accurate